# single device connects through cable modem but not router

Tags: networking

I have a docsis3 cable modem, a wifi6 orbi mesh and a bunch of devices. They all work fine. Today  I installed a Ring Access Controller, and it refuses to connect to the network when connected to the router. It connects fine when connected directly to the cable modem. Their instructions are non-existent, and I'm looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

I thought there may be some weird subnet or filtering thing going on, so I got a wifi bridge and connected the device to it and the bridge directly to the wifi signal on the modem (my modem has a built in access point). Same effect -- won't connect to the internet. Other devices on the bridge work fine.

Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: What do you mean by "it refuses to connect to the network"? Basic troubleshooting would be to check the network layers until you encounter the problem e.g. starting with layer one and going up from there (but it sounds like you already know this).

Comment: It appears to get an IP address (based on the DNS lease listing in the modem), but won't light its "connected" light. I'm assuming there's some sort of filtering/blocking happening, but the device has no management interface that I can get into, and no real information on why it's not connecting. I gave up and switched to the cellular version in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, not sure would it work or not:

Set docsis3 cable modem into the Router mode (some mode could do that), not the bridge mode. And login to your cable (PPPoE for most cable, based on ISP). Then set all your devices to: Obtain IP address automatically. and any device use LAN connect to the mode doesn't need to login anymore.

This might work, but it will make you have one more layer of NAT for most of your devices.

Comment: it's already in router mode bc of the wifi feature.

Comment: Ok, now I have no idea how to solve this, maybe ask the docsis3 cable modem provider (usually the ISP) would be a good idea, or ask someone else!